# How to Mock object without any Mock framework and without Interface in C#?

Tags: .net, mocking

I have the following the code in Main class

```
public class Price
{
public virtual double WebServiceCall(string symbol)
    {
        // Actual Code to call Web service
    }
}
```

I am Overriding that method in the Mock Class

```
 public class PriceMock : Price
    {
        public override double WebServiceCall(string symbol)
        {
            return 876.39;
        }
    }
```

How to Unit Test using Nunit Framework the Main class Price? I am interested in testing the Price class methods which should call the mock object methods

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you don't want to use interface, but to answer you question, you should be able to achieve this by using any dependency injection framework, and register Mock type in case of unit test.

I use unity so in UnitTest initialize i would register the something like below in the test initialize method.

```
var unityContainer = new UnityContainerFactory().Create();
UnityConfiguration.RegisterWithContainer(unityContainer);


unityContainer.RegisterType<Price, PriceMock>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you should bnot mock your system-under test. Doing so implies your class is doing too much and you have dependencies between your public API-methods. So you should extract another class from your current `Price`-class, which then performs the request. Then you can mock that class instead of your system under test.

Apart from this you can test your class by instantiating a `MockPrice` instead of your actual `Price`-class within your test. As the former only overrides those members you don't want to test, that won't change your methods being tested at all.

```
[Test]
public void RunTest()
{
    var target = new MockPrice();
    target.DoSomething(); // will evantually also call the overriden WebServiceCall-method
}
```

This however is pretty dirty and you should refactor as mentioned before.